# Can an odachi be called a katana?

Tags: nuances, kanji, names

I was arguing with a friend about the meaning of the word "katana". There are very large swords (some of them longer than 200cm) known as [odachi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C5%8Cdachi). My friend claimed that calling them a katana is not wrong since they are also swords and katana is just a general way to refer to swords. I checked from Wikipedia and words of some sword types include "katana" kanji (刀) in them. For example:

Katana:刀
Tachi:太刀
Odachi:大太刀

Does that mean he is right and they can be called as a katana, or is "katana" used for describing specific types of swords only?

Comment: Just to be clear were you having this discussion with regard to how to use the words in Japanese? Or were you discussing them in English and wanted to inform your English usage with the Japanese usage?

Comment: @Leebo We were discussing this in English, but we wanted to know usage of the words from the perspective of a Japanese speaker. Whatever a native Japanese speaker could call an odachi a katana. So yes to the your first sentence.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

刀 ("katana") **as a Japanese word** refers to (usually thin) single-edged swords in general, not swords in general. Etymologically, "kata" means "single". Double-edged swords are not called 刀, but most Western sabers and Persian shamshirs are safely called 刀 by Japanese speakers (although more specific names like サーベル and シャムシール are also common). [This section](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%88%80#%E4%B8%BB%E3%81%AA%E5%88%80%E3%81%AE%E7%A8%AE%E9%A1%9E) in Japanese Wikipedia lists the types of 刀 in the world. That said, when people say 刀 without any context, it primarily refers to Japanese ones used by Japanese samurai. When you need to specifically refer to Japanese 刀, you can use 日本刀 (nihontō).

Note that *katana* **as an English word** normally refers to Japanese swords only, and you probably have to respect this fact while you're speaking in English. Not all loaned words retain the original meaning. (A similar example is flute/フルート. In English, *flute* is a general term that includes [*shakuhachi*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shakuhachi), but フルート in Japanese refers only to western concert flutes. If I said *shakuhachi* is a type of フルート to a Japanese speaker, they might think I'm crazy.)

As for 大太刀 (odachi), from a Japanese speaker's point of view, it's certainly a subtype of 刀. If it doesn't match your image of classic *katana*(-as-English), I would say that's a problem in English, not Japanese.

**EDIT:** As is explained in sundowner's answer, Japanese people sometimes distinguish "打刀 (uchi-gatana) = (日本)刀 in the narrow sense" and "太刀 (tachi)", although the difference is not large. [This Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tachi) is based on the narrow sense of katana. So it's something like this:

[image]

So, you and your friend were both correct but were discussing based on the different definitions of the word. Which is correct depends on how strict you are categorizing Japanese weapons.

Comment: あ、そうか・・日本語で話してて「かたな」っていうのと、英語で "Katana" っていうのとでは…ってのがあるかもなんですね。

Comment: @Chocolate 日本語で「漢字」というと中国で使われている文字も全部合わせて「漢字」ですが、英語でkanjiというと日本語の漢字のみを指す、みたいな話もありますね

Comment: Yes, I wanted to know correctness from perspective of a Japanese speaker. Thanks for detailed explanation.

Answer (score 4):

I think he is right, in terms of the modern ordinary usage. Katana is just a generic name for sword.

Note that [the Japanese wikipedia for 大太刀](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%A4%A7%E5%A4%AA%E5%88%80) has the following.

> 大太刀とは初めに述べたように「長大な刀」のことであり、現代の分類では刀身の長さが3尺（約90cm）以上のものを指すのが一般的で...
>
> Odachi is a "long big katana" and in modern taxonomy refers to those with blades longer than 90cm.
>
> 日本刀において、刀身長による分類の方法には文献や研究者によって違いがあり、...従って、「大太刀」という言葉が指す刀剣の定義は常に一定というわけではない。
>
> In categorizing 日本刀, taxonomy by length varies depending on literature/researcher ... so the definition of 大太刀 is not always unique.

---

According to the following taxonomy in [The Japanese Sword Museum](https://www.touken.or.jp/museum/sword/making.html), 刀 in the narrower sense is generally shorter and has less curvature than 太刀. If following this, 大太刀 is (automatically) not a katana.

[image: swords]

Answer (score 4):

Yes and no. Technically, it looks like katana and tachi are classified separately when discussing Japanese swords. They have signatures on different sides of the blade, and are worn differently, with some other differences in finer details. However, in everyday usage of the word, katana is loosely an all-encompassing word that covers a wide range of (typically Japanese, but sometimes non-Japanese) single-edged swords.

[https://www.hyogo-c.ed.jp/~rekihaku-bo/historystation/rekihaku-meet/seminar/bugu-kacchuu/tk_intro1.html](https://www.hyogo-c.ed.jp/%7Erekihaku-bo/historystation/rekihaku-meet/seminar/bugu-kacchuu/tk_intro1.html)